Why doesn't the button respond when I set onPressed in onLoad?
Why doesn't the button respond when I set onPressed in onLoad?
The settings for position and the button itself (in this case, a TextComponent) are working, but for some reason, the function set for onPressed is not being called.
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/input.dart';
import 'package:flame/particles.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const FooApp());
}

class FooApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const FooApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: GameWidget.controlled(gameFactory: TextGame.new),
    );
  }
}

class TextGame extends FlameGame {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();

    await add(
      BButton(),
    );
  }
}

class BButton extends ButtonComponent {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();

    position = Vector2(size.x * 0.5, size.y * 0.5);
    onPressed = () { // NOT WORK
      print("Test");
    };
    button = TextComponent(
      text: 'B',
      textRenderer: TextPaint(
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 88,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Since I can't inherit from ButtonComponent, I'm using it without inheritance.

Try these:
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/input.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const FooApp());
}

class FooApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const FooApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: GameWidget.controlled(gameFactory: TextGame.new),
    );
  }
}

class TextGame extends FlameGame with HasTappableComponents {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();

    await add(
      BButton(
        position: Vector2(size.x * 0.5, size.y * 0.5),
        onPressed: () {
          print("Test");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BButton extends ButtonComponent {
  BButton({
    required Vector2 position,
    required VoidCallback onPressed,
  }) : super(
          position: position,
          button: TextComponent(
            text: 'B',
            textRenderer: TextPaint(
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 88,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: onPressed,
        );
}


I upvoted it. However, I want to write all the button processing on the inherited side.

It is because you haven't set a size of the button, so it will never "contain" the tap position.
This should work:
class BButton extends ButtonComponent {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();

    size = Vector2(200, 200);
    onPressed = () {
      print("Test");
    };
    button = TextComponent(
      text: 'B',
      textRenderer: TextPaint(
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 88,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


upvoted: I was able to press it. Why was the text displayed even though it had no size? / If it was used without inheritance, does that mean the size was set automatically? If so, I'm unsure what kind of values I should manually input.

Indeed it only set the size if the default constructor is used, not if it is extended like you've done. I fixed that here: https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/pull/3413
